# Htaccess look for pattern in url that end in .html and redirect

Tags: php, html, apache, redirect

So I have some 404 url in google that I want to redirect the user, so if the user accesses http://example.com/URL-THAT-DOESN'T-EXIST-ANYMORE.HTML

I want them to be redirected to the index page, my problem is that I can't figure out the pattern since I am new in regex.

It's very important to note that the url needs to end in .HTML othwerwise it shouldn't redirect. And I also need to specify the host in the redirect b/c I have multiple domains on the same app

Here is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 example.com^/(*)/?$ /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

This only redirects `domain.com/oldpage.html` to the index page or whatever the second argument is.

`L` means that it's the final redirect it bothers with, and sends you off straight away. `R=301` means it's a permanent redirect, and browsers will cache it. I think search engines take note too.

---

To redirect all html pages on the server use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes I want general thing, but the redirect needs to happen ONLY if the requested url ends in .html

Comment: @Uffo I've updated for all html pages. Also added a rather important escaping **backslash** that you don't want to forget.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
RedirectMatch 301 html$ /
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're redirecting specific pages that have moved, you can also just use `Redirect` instead.

```
Redirect 301 "/path/to/moved.html" "http://example.com/path/to/new.ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

You have to use `ErrorDocument` the easiest way other redirect

or

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ / [L,R]
```

This redirect all `.html` urls

[Other redirect methots](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#rewrite-and-redirection)